# KDE Plasma can't install. Help me

Tags: apt, kubuntu, kde, desktop-environments, plasma-5

When try to install KDE Plasma (Kubuntu Desktop) on Ubuntu 15.10 using 
`sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`

Then this error comming,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kubuntu-desktop : Depends: kinfocenter but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: kwin
                   Depends: plasma-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: powerdevil but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: sddm-theme-breeze but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: software-properties-kde but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: apport-kde but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: apturl-kde but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: gwenview but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kate but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kde-telepathy but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kdeconnect-plasma but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kscreen but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kubuntu-driver-manager but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kubuntu-notification-helper but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kwin-addons but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: milou but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: muon-discover but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: muon-notifier but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: pam-kwallet5 but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: plasma-nm but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: plasma-wallpapers-addons but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: plasma-widget-kimpanel but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: plasma-widgets-addons but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: print-manager but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

How to fix this? Please help me.
Thank you.